# Ruby on Rails routing, how do you force a subdomain / domain changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, routes, dns, subdomain

I have a couple of sub-domains on my rails app, and the main domain too.

Lets say I have a login route like this:

```
 match "login", :controller => "user_sessions", :action => "new"
```

Now this route can be accessed on all domains and sub-domains, e.g. :

```
porkjerkyicedcream.com/login
```

and...

```
admin.porkjerkyicedcream.com/login
```

My question is how do I force a redirect to remove the subdomain (or add it). So if someone visits **/login** on **admin.porkjerkyicedcream.com/login** they are redirected to the main domain (or vice versa)?

Cheers!

Edit:

1. I don't necessarily need the solution in the routing.
2. I want to avoid specifying and domain name in the app itself so It can be run it lots of places on lots of different domains (like a different dev domain)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a before_filter in your controller and then redirect appropriately. For example:

```
class UserSessionsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :ensure_proper_subdomain, :only => "new"

  def ensure_proper_subdomain
    if request.host_with_port != 'admin.porkjerkyicedcream'
      redirect_to params.merge({host: 'admin.porkjerkyicedcream'})
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It needs to be done without specifying a domain, so it can be deployed on multiple different domains.

Comment: To get around this issue you'll have to basically code the rule you want using the information provided. You might need to write config files depending on the domain or collection of domains that your app is deployed on. You have the domain (request.host_with_port), so you can use that information to determine where you want to redirect. You can also create a config class to handle the configuration and routing for you, but you'll have to figure out when you want to redirect on your own - we can't provide that in a solution here.

Comment: Cheers man, I went with this approach and used some regex to check for the correct domain.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done in routing file. But in any case, you can always create [a custom filter](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) and redirect users according to the current domain/path.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could manage this in application_controller if you add:

```
  def default_url_options(options={})
    #add whatever logic you want
    { :host => "example.com" }
  end
```

Comment: It needs to be done without specifying a domain, so it can be deployed on multiple different domains.